# How do you make a line graph with multiple lines from multiple variables in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two dataframes and I want to plot a comparison between them. The plot and dataframes look like so

```
df2019 <- data.frame(Role = c("A","B","C"),Women_percent = c(65,50,70),Men_percent = c(35,50,30), Women_total = 
c(130,100,140), Men_total = c(70,100,60))
df2016 <- data.frame(Role= c("A","B","C"),Women_percent = c(70,45,50),Men_percent = c(30,55,50),Women_total = 
c(140,90,100), Men_total = c(60,110,100))

all_melted <- reshape2::melt(
  rbind(cbind(df2019, year=2019), cbind(df2016, year=2016)),
  id=c("year", "Role"))
```

Theres no reason I need the data in melted from, I just did it because I was plotting bar graphs with it, but now I need a line graph and I dont know how to make line graphs in melted form, and dont know how to keep that 19/16 tag if not in melted frame. When i try to make a line graph I dont know how to specify what "variable" will be used. I want the lines to be the Women,Men percent values, and the label to be the totals.[image: Should look like this with year in legend, 2016 dotted] (in this picture the geom_text is the percent values, I want it to use the total values)

Crucially I want the linetype to be dotted in 2016 and for the legend to show that

Comment: what is the dashed line for`?

Comment: @Stephan just to distinguish 2019 and 2016, so basically Im asking how to make the same plot with the linetypes in the legend. From what I gathered its not really possible unless you merge the dataframes like how I did in the example I showed.
I only have the 2019 line being labeled becasue its more important

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be simplest to `rbind` the two frames after labelling them with their year, then reshape the result so that you have columns for role, year, gender, percent and total.

I would then use a bit of alpha scale trickery to hide the points and labels from 2016:

```r
df2016$year <- 2016
df2019$year <- 2019

rbind(df2016, df2019) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = 2:5, names_sep = "_", names_to = c("Gender", "Type")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Type) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Role, percent, color = Gender, 
             linetype = factor(year), 
             group = paste(Gender, year))) +
  geom_line(size = 1.3) +
  geom_point(size = 10, aes(alpha = year)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = total, alpha = year), colour = "black") +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("#07aaf6", "#ef786f")) +
  scale_alpha(range = c(0, 1), guide = guide_none()) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(2, 1)) +
  labs(y = "Percent", color = "Gender", linetype = "Year")
```

[image]